# How can I submit a new query in an angular application?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms, angularjs

Let me start by saying this: this is my first forray into angularJS.

I am building an angular app with a feature where you can write sql directly against a database. Security issues aside (I am the only person who will be using this app when it is done).

I built a service on the backend that will return a json object result of whatever query is passed in as params[:query]['input'] (the backend is a rails app).

From the front end, I'd like to pass in a query parameter named input. So in the form on the angular app, I've created this form:

```
<form action="/path/to/service" method="post">
  <textarea id="input" name="input"></textarea>
  <button id="execute" name="execute">Execute Query</button>
</form>
```

However, this is not asynchronous, the page attempts to redirect and the data doesn't come in as it should.

Comment: you need to use $http for async requests...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [AngularJS tutorial - REST and custom services](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_11), there you'll find what services provided by Angular you need to use to make an Ajax call. I suggest you read the whole tutorial if you didn't yet.

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS is used for designing single page applications.

So once your application is loaded, the page won't get refreshed and all the server communication is done async using angular's feature `$http`.

If you want to submit any form, you can use `$http` like this

HTML:

```
<form ng-submit="sub()">
    ...
</form>
```

Then in your controller:

```
function ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.sub = function() {
        $http.post(url,data,headers)
            .success(function(data,status,headers,config) {
                //do something with data (response)
            })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a controller and a factory. With the ng-click directive you call a function in the controller that calls a function in the factory. The factory returns a promise that the controller handles to put the result in the scope. Something like this:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, dataService) {
  $scope.getData = function(query){
    var url = prepareYourURL(query) //HERE YOU PREPARE YOUR URL
    dataService.getData(url).then(function(result){
      $scope.data = result.data;
    });
  };
});

app.factory('dataService', function($http){
  return {
    getData: function(url) {
      return $http.get(url);
    }
  };
});
```

And from your Html you call it like this:

```
  <textarea ng-model="query"></textarea>
  <button ng-click="getData(query)">Execute Query</button>
```

Then you can just present the data in the view as you like. Start by just doing this

```
<p>{{data}}</p>
```

and you will see everything you've fetched.